# Unable connect to HBASE using WSO2-DAS server

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

I am new to wso2 DAS. Trying to connect HBase using wso2-DAS. configured data source as required. Than creating event steam to store the table and its values. getting licence error as below.

ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.eventsink.AnalyticsEventStoreDeployer} -  Unable to deploy the event store: hive_test.xml. Unable to create the table - hive_test for tenant id : -1234. d.  ~  ~ WSO2 Inc. licenses this file to you under the Apache License,  ~ Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except  ~ in compliance with the License.  ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at  ~  ~ http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0  ~  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,  ~ software distributed under the License is distributed on an  ~ "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY  ~ KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the  ~ specific language governing permissions and limitations  ~ under the License.  -->            Error

## Error Occurred

org.wso2.carbon.analytics.api.exception.AnalyticsServiceException: Unable to create the table - hive_test for tenant id : -1234.             Error

## Error Occurred

at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.api.internal.client.AnalyticsAPIHttpClient.createTable(AnalyticsAPIHttpClient.java:292)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.api.CarbonAnalyticsAPI.createTable(CarbonAnalyticsAPI.java:139)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.eventsink.AnalyticsEventStoreDeployer.addEventStore(AnalyticsEventStoreDeployer.java:108)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.eventsink.AnalyticsEventStoreDeployer.deploy(AnalyticsEventStoreDeployer.java:78)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with an evensink file. It's strange you seeing a part of a license file here.

Do you have `hive_test.xml` inside `repository/deployment/server/eventsink/` directory? Please double check the content of the file. Something is wrong with it.

Comment: The issue got resolved after adding Apache licence 2.0 copyright  in comments in analytics-config.xml file.